# PyCharm не видит компоненты библиотеки aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу телеграм-бота и возникла проблема, PyCharm не может определить некоторые компоненты библотеки aiogram, переустанавливал PyCharm, Python, ничего не помогает, на скрине можно увидеть, что библиотека скачана[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: наверное потому что нужен `Dispatcher`, а не `Dispather`?

Comment: Этот недочёт я заметил, исправил, непомогло

Comment: покажите вывод команды `pip list`, вы не используете виртуальную среду?

Comment: aiofiles           23.1.0
aiogram            3.0.0b8
pip                22.3.1
property-manager   3.0
pydantic           1.10.7
pyreadline3        3.4.1
setuptools         66.0.0
six                1.16.0
typing_extensions  4.5.0
verboselogs        1.7
wheel              0.38.4
yarl               1.8.2
Используется venv в PyCharm

Comment: просто ваши скриншоты говорят об обратном

Comment: Я создал новый проект, думал это поможет решить проблему, нет, с виртуальной средой не работает, и без неё не работает

Comment: создавайте новый чистый проект с виртуальной средой, устанавливайте aiogram в нее, импортируйте `Dispatcher`, а так не понятно куда вы устанавливали и от куда пытаетесь импортировать

Comment: ПКМ по корневой директории и выбрать пункт Mark Directory as -> Sources Root